# Why don't we use JavaScript objects to store data instead of MySQL or any database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, object

When I started to learn PHP & MySQL, This question was in my brain... Why don't we use JavaScript objects to store data instead of MySQL or any database?
We can get the user input using DOM methods and store it into arrays if it was only name & password and if it was bigger (address, phone, postal code... etc) store it into objects?

Comment: What if the application stops running?

Comment: The second that server goes offline, the object would erase.

Comment: there are many developers, we can use any js framework... it can make it happen

Comment: Data needs to be _persisted_ somehow in most applications. If one views JSON as “the serialization of a limited subset of JavaScript data objects”, then it’s already ‘done’ with persistent storage providers that use such models.. eg. CouchDB, MongoDB, JSON DB, or even a “plain JSON file/resource” etc.

Comment: On the server?  If it's only in memory you'd better hope your server can run for 20 years without crashing or needing to restart after an update.  Also that all data can fit in the RAM of the process.  Also that there is only one JavaScript process shared by all incoming  connections.

Comment: Go ahead and try it and let us know how it works out

Comment: A MySQL database is, at its most basic level, a file on the hard drive. You don't have to use MySQL to persist data to the hard drive. As you mention, you could use CSV, JSON, key-value pairs, and so on. The reason why we use MySQL is because it's really good at organizing and managing the data.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to describe Document Databases. Otherwise it's like saying, "why do we need a database, we can just use the data structures of our languages?"

In addition to unexpected application halts there is the issue of memory and safety... If a program needs to handle a lot of data, and it is relying on its own data structures, imagine the number of objects that will have to be created... All on the RAM... Safety, there is a lot to say about that.

Comment: we can make specific files that contain data

Comment: @BasemSleem -  in other words, a database file.

Comment: Databases are files, eventually, you're reinventing the wheel; in this case I believe it will be more painful than not to.